Ros2 Launch file does not work
I follow a tutorial about Ros2.
In the chapter of Launch files I have got the following Python program:
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
import os
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch_ros.parameter_descriptions import ParameterValue
from launch.substitutions import Command, LaunchConfiguration
def generate_launch_description():
model_arg = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    name="model",
    default_value=os.path.join(get_package_share_directory("bumperbot_description"), "urdf", "bumperbot.urdf.xacro"),
    description="Absolute path to robot URDF file"
)

robot_description = ParameterValue(Command(["xacro ", LaunchConfiguration("model")]), value_type=str)

robot_state_publisher = Node(
    package="robot_state_publisher",
    executable="robot_state_publisher",
    parameters=[{"robot_description": robot_description}]
)

joint_state_publisher_gui = Node(
    package="joint_state_publisher_gui",
    executable="joint_state_publisher_gui"
)

rviz_node = Node(
    package="rviz2",
    executable="rviz2",
    name="rviz2",
    output="screen",
    arguments=["-d", os.path.join(get_package_share_directory("bumperbot_description"),"rviz", "display.rviz")]

)

return LaunchDescription({
    model_arg,
    robot_state_publisher,
    joint_state_publisher_gui,
    rviz_node
})

But the output of the Console is:
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/samy/.ros/log/2024-10-10-22-16-03-158148-Samy-5531
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): launch configuration 'model' does not exist
I have used colcon build and I have sources a new Console but it does not work. Can anybody give my a help?

You might want to check out ROS2 Using substitutuins.
The LaunchConfiguration("model") is not defined yet when called upon in model_arg.

model_arg = DeclareLaunchArgument(
   name="model", default_value=os.path.join(get_package_share_directory("bumperbot_description"), "urdf", "bumperbot.urdf.xacro"),
   description="Absolute path to robot URDF file"
)
robot_description = ParameterValue(Command(["xacro ", LaunchConfiguration("model")]), value_type=str)
...


I recommend a setup like this:
model = LaunchConfiguration("model")
model_arg = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    name="model",
    default_value=os.path.join(get_package_share_directory("bumperbot_description"), "urdf", "bumperbot.urdf.xacro"),
    description="Absolute path to robot URDF file"
)
robot_description = ParameterValue(Command(["xacro ", model]), value_type=str)
...

